# RedirectMatch 301 ^/cgi- http://www.example.com/cgi/ubb/Ultimate.cgi doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have successfully corrected all of the Google crawler errors except /cgi-
I don't know much but it seems strange to me. (www.somedomain.com is not my real site)

http://www.somedomain.com/cgi-xxx 
redirects OK
but 
http://www.somedomain.com/cgi- 
doesn't ????

This is the .htaccess

RedirectMatch 301 ^/cgi- http://www.somedomain.com/cgi/ubb/Ultimate.cgi

Please help... **this has been an open question for 13 days.**

Comment: What is the problem? The code posted is ok and it's working fine on my apache server.